# HTML Table different column text not aligned to same line

Tags: html, css

The text in different 's inside a html table is not aligned on the same line.
One of column of this table has multiple lines of text.For example,

```
Header1|Header2
---------------
       |This is
Ex     |an Example
```

If the second column has multiple lines of text, then both the column text does not start on the same line which is required.
Currently i have not applied any styles to the table/td

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: I suggest you provide relevant code so we all know what you're working with. Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the text of the table is aligned to middle by default, you need to set the alignment of the text so that you can achieve what you want. Use `vertical-align:top` so that even if the 2nd column has multiple lines, both of the text will start at the top of the table.

```
th,td{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

For visualization here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb88re2f/).

Comment: Thank You so much. This is what  required for me.

Comment: Glad I can help. :)